# Inline Assembler: Invalid reference syntax

Tags: assembly, pascal, freepascal, i386

two days ago I got the following error of the Free Pascal Compiler 2.2.0:

```
Error: Invalid reference syntax
```

Prehistory:

I wanted to compile a pascal source with some included assembly directives for the platform "i386-linux"

```
procedure drawpixel(x,y,color: word); assembler;
asm
  mov ax, y
  mov bx, x
  mov dl, color

  mov cx, 320
  mul cx
  add ax, bx
  mov di, ax
  mov [es:di], dl /// Right at [es:di] the inline assembler gives this annoying exception
  ret
end;
```

Could somebody help me, please.

Comment: Well, are you in linux? This code is for 16 bit real mode, it won't work in linux even if you get it to assemble. (As is, it won't even work in real mode because `es` is not set up.)

Comment: After `mul cx`, the `DX` register is 0. The `mov [es:di], dl` instruction will not display the color! Remember that `DL` is part of `DX`. Change this:   `mov cx, color` `mov dx, 320` `mul dx` `add bx, ax` `mov [es:bx], cl`.

Comment: It could be that the syntax is `mov es:[di], dl` on your assembler.

Comment: @SepRoland: Or since the target platform is "i386-linux", `imul bx, y, 320` / `add bx, x`, if you still want to use 16-bit operand-size.  (Or multiply by 5 with LEA and multiply by 64 with a shift, 320 = 5 * 64).  But yeah, overwriting DL with `mul` is a bug.

Answer (score 5):

As the commentators have already indicated, this is 16-bit assembler which won't work without modification in 32-bit.

Besides that using a 16-bit register for indirect destination ([di]) is weird, the ES segment in 32-bit apps is the same as the DS segment, so probably not what you want (which I assume is supposed to be some mode-X screen buffer), but would ram it somewhere in the first 64kb of application memory, which is at least partially protected against write to trap zero pointer references.

You'll need to rethink this, accessing graphics screens like in dos is not possible in Linux.